# How can i prevent from creating multiple instances in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new on Codeigniter and i have a question.
In controller classes i need to use session, request and validation objects in every method So for each method i have to create an instance of them like below:

```
$session=\Config\Services::session();
$validation=\Config\Services::validation();
$request=\Config\Services::request();
```

How can i make one instance for whole the controller methods?
I tried to creat property but it seems that i can not use an object as a property
I would be thankful if you help me with that

Answer (score 1):

Make them globals - some suggestions of different approaches for how to achieve this in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013397/codeigniter-best-place-to-declare-global-variable)